# Un nom pratique pour l’application naturelle en théorie des groupes

Tags: terminologie, mathématiques

J'essaie de m’accoutumer au français des preuves mathématiques. Faire une preuve requiert plus de connaissance à l’égard des modalités et des mots. La toile est un bon moyen de recueillir des renseignements, mais parfois quelque chose semble introuvable.

Cette fois-ci, je vous pose une question concernant l’algèbre que Galois a conçue.
Un ensemble muni d’une loi « * » (satisfaisant plusieurs exigences) est appelé un *groupe*. 
Un sous-ensemble *H* du ledit groupe est appelé *sous-groupe* lorsqu’il est lui-même un groupe par rapport à la loi donnée. On l’appelle *distingué* lorsque la conjugaison avec tout *g* laisse stable *H*. La fonction *g* qui envoie un élément *x* vers sa classe suivant le sous-groupe est parfois nommée « l’application naturelle », pas vrai ?

Aux Pays-Bas, on emploie une façon adroite pour exprimer que l’« on applique l’application naturelle reliée au *H* sur *G* ».  Je tente de la traduire comme ci :
« on divise *G* sur *H* »
(Cela sous-entend bien sûr que *H* est un sous-groupe distingué.)

J’espère que quelqu’un peut confirmer où infirmer qu’une expression pareille est utilisée en français.

Comment: http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groupe_quotient

Comment: J'ai suivi je lien que vous m'avez donné, mais sans y trouver une réponse. Pouvez-vous me dire comment ça s’exprime, explicitement?

Comment: Je suis pas francophone, mais selon l'article de Wikipedia je pense que l'expression que vous cherchez est "le groupe quotient de G par H".

Comment: Et ce que tu appelles « application naturelle » c'est le « morphisme canonique » ou la « projection canonique ».

Comment: Ou *projection sur G/H*. Ce n'est d'ailleurs pas exclusif aux groupes quotients. Ça se dit pour n'importe quelle relation d'équivalence. Par contre par chez moi on dit plutôt « G quotienté par H » ou « G sur H ».

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On quotiente G par H. En fait, on cette terminologie s'applique pour n'importe quel ensemble où on identifie des éléments par une relation d'équivalence : on parlera du quotient de l'ensemble par la relation d'équivalence pour l'ensemble obtenu.

Dans le cas d'un sous-groupe, la relation d'équivalence est définie par x~y si x et y ont la même image par la projection canonique (ce que tu appelles l'application naturelle) et on parle de quotient de G par H en sous-entendant la relation d'équivalence. Si de plus le sous-groupe est distingué, on appelle G/H groupe quotient.